# Django + Extjs 5.1.1

Tags: django

I have a strange django error, that i would you to help me please.

The error occurs when I try to load django templates.

I work with Sencha ver 5.1.1 and Django ver 1.8.2.

When I try to load `index.html`, a file created by Sencha Cmd file without django (directly), with hard path like this:

```
<script id="microloader"
type="application/javascript"
src="/frontend/extjs/bootstrap.js">
</script>
```

It works as excepted.

But, if I load `index.html` with django with as a templates who look like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script id="microloader"
type="application/javascript"
src="{% static "bootstrap.js" %}">
</script>
```

On firefox it show the following error :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

manifest = Ext.manifest = JSON.parse(result.content);
bootstrap.js col:50 line 1513
```

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

it is appear that firefox CAN NOT run with out web security as chrome does.
Because of that all my testing was unable to run and fail.
If you running test inside your lab you may want to use chrome as the

following :
"chrome --disable-web-security"

Please note , this ONLY FOR TESTING !!!! not for production.
After I realize that my django finally run as expected and load the index.html as a templates as i need.

Thank all for all your effort to help